# store variable number of comma separated value in a single cells in a database

Tags: database, model, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am writing the model for the play framework with ebean.
Consider 3 tables - **Student, Company, Requirements**

1. Student belongs to a department(attribute).
2. Company has Requirements.
3. The requirement can be students of a particular department or one or more number of departments.

Every company has different types of department required.
**How do i write the model for this condition for department in Requirement table? and also how to i map it to the students department?**

Answer (score 0):

This is typical task for ManyToMany relationship with usage of middle table for collecting it, Ebean has simple annotation, which will create valid tables... for an example (from top of head) Company model can use:

```
@ManyToMany
public List<Requirement> requirements;
```

Comment: i wanted to ask like company X wants students from department B & C, Company Y wants student from department B, C & D. how do i handle this condition while storing this into the company's reuirement table since every requirement has variable number of departments and then how do i map it to student's department if i wanted to retrieve students belonging to the company's required department.